# Mockito verify the call to a mock method inside a mock call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have model mock class where i verify a call from another DAO mock object. But this call is not happening to model class and only verify happens on DAO class.

```
public class ApplicationTests {

@Mock
private Card card; 

@Mock
private JourneyDAO journeyDAO;

@InjectMocks
private JourneyServiceImpl journeyServiceImpl;

private static final Double ZERO_VALUE = 0.0;
private static final Double INITIAL_BALANCE = 30D;
private static final String NAME = "name";

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(card.getBalance()).thenReturn(INITIAL_BALANCE);
    when(card.getName()).thenReturn(NAME);
}


@Test
public void startJourneyInZone1_Test() {
    barrier = new Barrier(card, direction.IN, journeyType.TUBE, Stations.Holborn);
    journeyServiceImpl.startTubeJourney(barrier);
    verify(card, times(1)).addBalance(MAX_FARE * -1);// this call is not heppening
    verify(journeyDAO, times(1)).startTubeJourney(barrier);// this is working 
}

}
```

DAO class method looks like as below

```
public void startTubeJourney(Barrier barrier) {
    if(barrier.getModeOfJourney() == TravelMode.TUBE) {
        if(barrier.getDirection() == Direction.IN) {
            boardingAtZone = barrier.getZone();
            barrier.getCard().addBalance(MAX_FARE * -1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below error while running the Test. Please ignore the package and class names mismatch as i am making some example case.

```
Wanted but not invoked:
card.addBalance(0.7000000000000002d);
-> at com.rcard.travel.ApplicationTests.endTubeJourneyTest(ApplicationTests.java:69)

Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

at com.travel.ApplicationTests.endTubeJourneyTest(ApplicationTests.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Barrier class looks like

```
public class Barrier {

    private Card card;
    private Direction direction;
    private TravelMode modeOfJourney;
    private Stations zone;

    public Barrier(Card card, Direction direction, TravelMode mode, Stations zone) {
        this.card = card;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.modeOfJourney = mode;
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public String getZone() {
        return Stations.elementOf(this.zone);
    }

    public void setZone(Stations zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public Card getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public void setCard(Card card) {
        this.card = card;
    }

    public Direction getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(Direction direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public TravelMode getModeOfJourney() {
        return modeOfJourney;
    }

    public void setModeOfJourney(TravelMode modeOfJourney) {
        this.modeOfJourney = modeOfJourney;
    }  

}
```

Comment: can you show our Barrier class

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Because `journeyDAO` is a mock, this means the real `journeyDAO.startTubeJourney()` is not being called.

One possible fix would be to use a real `JourneyDAO`, so `card.addBalance()` does get called, but this does mean the one test is testing both the service and DAO classes.

Alternatively, I would be tempted to write a separate test for `JourneyDAO`. This could call its `startTubeJourney()`, and verify the `card.addBalance()`.  This would mean the current `verify()` against the mock `journeyDAO.startTubeJourney()` could stay.

Comment: I think there will not much difference when i write a separate test for JourneyDAO and the current test.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line

```
@Mock
private JourneyDAO journeyDAO;
```

You are trying to verify the method that belongs to mocked object `journeyDAO`. If you want to have `when...then` as well as call real method when it's available, you need to use `@Spy` annotation.

```
@Spy
private JourneyDAO journeyDAO;
```

will fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure? I did run this gist on local and it works perfectly fine.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6a946ab68587e3a6cd326d07bc7270e7